# Problema con Treelist de DevExpress

Tags: asp.net, mvc, devexpress

Mi problema es que mi treelist no hace nada luego de que expando los nodos.
Esta es mi vista

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EstructuraFinanciera";
}
@if (Session["username"] != null)
{
  <text>
    Bienvenido @Session["username"].ToString()
  </text>
  <script>
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
  </script>
<br />


}
else
{
    Response.Redirect(Url.Action("Login", "Inicio"));
}

<br />
<hr />



@Html.Action("_TreeListPartial")
```

Mi Vista parcial que la crea el wizard de devexpress

```
@{
                    var treeList = Html.DevExpress().TreeList(settings => {
                        settings.Name = "TreeList";
                        settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = 
 "Contabilidad", Action = "TreeListPartial" };


 settings.SettingsEditing.AddNewNodeRouteValues = new { Controller = 
"Contabilidad", Action = "TreeListPartialAddNew" };
                        settings.SettingsEditing.UpdateNodeRouteValues = new 
{ Controller = "Contabilidad", Action = "TreeListPartialUpdate" };
                        settings.SettingsEditing.DeleteNodeRouteValues = new 
{ Controller = "Contabilidad", Action = "TreeListPartialDelete" };

                        settings.CommandColumn.Visible = true;
                        settings.CommandColumn.NewButton.Visible = true;
                        settings.CommandColumn.DeleteButton.Visible = true;
                        settings.CommandColumn.EditButton.Visible = true;

                                settings.KeyFieldName = "ID";
                        settings.ParentFieldName = "IdPadre";
                                settings.Columns.Add(
                            column => {
                                column.FieldName = "ID";
                                column.Visible = false;
                            }
                        );
                                settings.Columns.Add(
                            column => {
                                column.FieldName = "IdPadre";
                                column.Visible = false;
                            }
                        );
                                settings.Columns.Add(
                            column => {
                                column.FieldName = "Nombre";
                            }
                        );
                                settings.Columns.Add(
                            column => {
                                column.FieldName = "Comentario";
                            }
                        );
                                settings.Columns.Add(
                            column => {
                                column.FieldName = "NaturalezaDeudora";
                            }
                        );
                                settings.Columns.Add(
                            column => {
                                column.FieldName = "EsCuentaBalanza";
                            }
                        );
                                settings.Columns.Add(
                            column => {
                                column.FieldName = "EsCuenteResultado";
                            }
                        );
                                settings.Columns.Add(
                            column => {
                                column.FieldName = "Codigo";
                            }
                        );
                                settings.Columns.Add(
                            column => {
                                column.FieldName = "Mayor";
                            }
                        );

                        settings.SettingsPager.Visible = true;
                        settings.SettingsSelection.Enabled = true;
                    });
                        if (ViewData["EditError"] != null){

 treeList.SetEditErrorText((string)ViewData["EditError"]);
                    }
 }   
 @treeList.Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

Y pues mis nodos despliegados, de alli no pasa

[image]
No se que puede ser. De antemano gracias a quien me pueda ayudar.

Comment: De preferencia que tu codigo sea texto es mas facil para hacer las pruebas

Comment: Ya lo cambie amigo.

Comment: Podrías definir "no hace nada", lo que entiendo es que se congela.

Comment: Asi mismo, no puedo expandir otro nodo, ni las acciones de borrar, eliminar y editar

Comment: ¿Cómo expandir si todos se encuentran expandidos? Eso es lo que veo en la imagen.

Comment: Tenia un error de js estaba llamando un script de mas. Y me daba un error porque ese se mandaba a llamar y ese como q no tenia funciones de los botones. Gracias de igual manera